# C++ Как правильно указать пути включения директивой #include к .h файлу из другой папки

Tags: c++, файлы, репозиторий

Вопрос как максимально кратко указать путь к другой папке с помощью #include когда есть такой репозиторий:

```
Test
1. Header Files
    1.1 Test.hpp //объявление 
2. Resource Files
    2.1 Test.cpp //реализация
3. Main.cpp // исполняемый файл
```

Как мне правильно указать в Test.cpp директиву Test.hpp с помощью #include".../Test.hpp" без полного пути к файлу.

Например я в .json файлах могу указать "${FileDirName}/Resource File/Test.cpp" для сборки. Могу ли я сделать что-то подобное в .cpp файле.

Comment: ```#include "../Header Files/Test.hpp"```    или в  настройках проекта установите путь к включаемым файлам, тогда можно будет так: ```#include "Test.hpp"```

Comment: Если не хотите писать `"../Test.hpp"`, у компиляторов есть флаги, добавляющие папку к путям поиска хедеров.

Answer (score 1):

```
// ------------ //
// - test.hpp - //
// ------------ //
#ifndef __TEST_HPP__
#define __TEST_HPP__

class A {
    int a;

public:
    A(int);
    
    int get_a() const;
};

#endif

// ------------ //
// - test.cpp - //
// ------------ //

#include "../HeaderFiles/test.hpp"

A::A(int a): a(a) {}

int A::get_a() const { return a; }

// ------------ //
// - main.cpp - //
// ------------ //

#include "HeaderFiles/test.hpp"

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    A a(5);
    std::cout << a.get_a() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Напомню, что имена с двойным подчеркиванием вначале зарезервированы для реализаций.